# Java/Android Get Parent Instance For Invoking Method

Tags: java, android, invoke

I have a method which I am trying to call dynamically. That method has an argument 'stringValue'.  The method I am trying to invoke is in the parent (receivers??) class.
I can't figure out how to get the reference back to the parent

```
java.lang.reflect.Method method;
method = Class.forName("com.blah.MyActivity").getMethod("myFunction", String.class);
method.invoke(this,stringValue);
```

Gives the error: 
 
'Message expected receiver of type com.blah.MyActivity, but got com.blah.MyActivity$SubTask'

Comment: From the error message, I listed, 'SubTask' is the class I'm currently in and 'com.blah.MyActivity' is the class/instance I would like to be in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you want:

```
method.invoke(MyActivity.this, stringValue);
```

The `MyActivity.this` part is the way of getting to the enclosing instance of `MyActivity`.

See [section 15.8.4 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.4) for more details.

Comment: THANK YOU ! The infamous Jon Skeet STRIKES AGAIN.  Thank you for being so friendly and helpful.